# What's the Emoji type used in WhatsApp app? Are they using one of the emoji vendors from below link?

Tags: unicode, emoji

http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-released.html

Looking at the vendors from the link, WhatsApp emojis seems to match with Sams. Is that the one they use ? Or they encode their emojis differently.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp uses Apple emoji images for emoji support on all platforms, including Android, Windows and the web. This differs from most apps which use the native emojis available for each platform.

Ref: https://emojipedia.org/whatsapp/

I think WhatsApp used internally Unicode but for display purpose use images.